# Stop logged in users from visiting login route in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I have the following codes from my app:
**store/modules/user.js**

```js
const state = {
  user: {
    id: "",
    email: "",
    orgName: "",
  },
  isLoggedin: false,
};

const getters = {
  currentUser: (state) => state,
  isLoggedin: (state) => state.isLoggedin,
};
```

**router/index.js**

```js
const routes = [{
    path: "/sign-up",
    name: "Signup",
    component: () =>
      import ("../views/auth/Signup.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Login",
    component: () =>
      import ("../views/auth/Login.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "Dashboard",
    component: () =>
      import ("../views/Dashboard.vue"),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    },
  },

  {
    path: "/post",
    component: () =>
      import ("../views/Index"),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    },
    children: [{
        path: "/",
        name: "posts",
        component: () =>
          import ("../views/post/Index.vue"),
      },
      {
        path: "create",
        component: () =>
          import ("../views/post/Create.vue"),
      },
      {
        path: "view",
        component: () =>
          import ("../views/booking/View.vue"),
      },
    ],
  },
];

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some((x) => x.meta.requiresAuth);
  const isLoggedin = store.getters["isLoggedin"];
  console.log(router);
  if (requiresAuth && !isLoggedin) {
    next("/");
  } else if (requiresAuth && isLoggedin) {
    next();
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

With the above code only authenticated users can access post routes (create, view, index). But logged in users still can visit login page and relogin.

`state.user.isLoggedin` is set to true when user is logged in sucessfully.

I would like to redirect logged in users to `/dashboard` when they hit login url.

What would be the best logic for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Just like you made the `requireAuth` flow, you can also create a `requireGuest` flow:

```
const routes = [{
    path: "/sign-up",
    name: "Signup",
    meta: {
      requiresGuest: true
    },
    component: () =>
      import ("../views/auth/Signup.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Login",
    meta: {
      requiresGuest: true
    },
    component: () =>
      import ("../views/auth/Login.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "Dashboard",
    component: () =>
      import ("../views/Dashboard.vue"),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    },
  },

  {
    path: "/post",
    component: () =>
      import ("../views/Index"),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    },
    children: [{
        path: "/",
        name: "posts",
        component: () =>
          import ("../views/post/Index.vue"),
      },
      {
        path: "create",
        component: () =>
          import ("../views/post/Create.vue"),
      },
      {
        path: "view",
        component: () =>
          import ("../views/booking/View.vue"),
      },
    ],
  },
];

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some((x) => x.meta.requiresAuth);
  const requiresGuest = to.matched.some((x) => x.meta.requiresGuest);
  const isLoggedin = store.getters["isLoggedin"];
  console.log(router);
  if (requiresAuth && !isLoggedin) {
    next("/");
  } else if (requiresGuest && isLoggedin) {
    next("/dashboard");
  }  else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `beforeEnter` on the login route to redirect logged in users to the dashboard.

```js
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Login",
    component: () =>
      import ("../views/auth/Login.vue"),
    beforeEnter: async (to, from, next) => {
      const isLoggedIn = store.getters["isLoggedin"];

      if (isLoggedIn) {
          return next("/dashboard");
      }

      next();
    },
  },
```